# Arduino code working via IDE, not via PlatformIO Arduino code

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, ide, platformio

I have a working Arduino code. The code works as intended when I upload it to an Arduino Nano using the old bootloader via the Arduino IDE. However, when I upload the same code via PlatformIO, the code uploads successfully but does not work as intended. There are no errors or warnings during the upload process, and I am having trouble figuring out what could be causing the issue.

Now for troubleshooting I am using simple blink example.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                      // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                      // wait for a second
}
```

*1st PlatformIO configuration .ini*

```
[env:nanoatmega328]
platform = atmelavr
board = nanoatmega328
framework = arduino
debug_port = COM3
monitor_speed = 115200
```

I have also tried following but no luck.

*2nd PlatformIO configuration .ini*

```
[env:nanoatmega328]
platform = atmelavr
board = nanoatmega328
framework = arduino
board_oldbootloader = true
debug_port = COM3
monitor_speed = 115200
```

Any suggestions on how to debug this problem or what might be causing the issue? Thank you.

Comment: The blink function gets programmed by the IDE. In case I program with Arduino IDE the code gets uploaded to the board and works as intended (i.e. LED blinks). In case I program with PlatformIO the code gets uploaded to the board but doesn't work as intended (i.e. (The LED doesn't blink).

Comment: It's very weird. I have tried different solutions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: turn on the LED in setup ... leave `loop()` empty ... what happens?

Comment: print the value of LED_BUILTIN to serial monitor to see its value ... also, try referring to the LED pin by number

Comment: My apologies. Not familiar, 1st ever question.

Comment: Ok, a weird thing happened. :D
1) I did as you said. I left the loop empty and turned on led in the setup. Result: The LED stays off.
2) I uncommented the loop and uploaded again. The LED started blinking.
3) The problem resolved itself. Any idea what went right.

Comment: you never loaded the sketch the first time around

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar behavior for a while and nothing I would change in the PlatformIO .ini configuration file seemed to help. I tried to re-init and clean the project, but also didn't seem to help.

Eventually, what worked for me was to start a new fresh PlatformIO project and migrate the files over.

I suspect that under certain conditions (that may be related to the project settings), PlatformIO fails to upload the script, yet it claims that the upload was successful.